# Where in what files does the binary reference information be saved in VS.NET 2010 web project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project

I have a vendor help develop a web project using VS.NET 2010. I got the delivered source codes from source code control system and tried to build it. There is an error message showing that one namespace is unknown, which is due to missing the reference of a .dll.

However, the vendor did add that reference into the web project and successfully built it in his own development environment. I know that for class library project, those reference information is saved in .csproj file. What about a file system web project? I did not see this information either in the .sln or the web application folder. Does anyone know where it is? I need to manually add the reference every time, which does not make any sense.

Comment: Is this a web application project, or a web site "project"?

Comment: It is a web site project.

Answer (score 0):

check the web.config file in the system.web/assemblies element